# Bookmark an article in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a functionality for a user to be able to bookmark and article and remove the article from his bookmarks as well. The functionality to bookmark an article works just fine, but when I try to remove the article from the bookmarks then it does not work and instead it inserts the same record but with the article_id being NULL.

Here is my controller:

```
public function postBookmark() {
    $user_id    = Auth::user()->id;
    $article_id = Input::get('id');
    $bookmark   = Bookmark::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->where('article_id', '=', $article_id);
    $article    = Article::where('id', '=', $article_id);
    $article    = $article->first();

    // I want to check if the article has been already bookmarked by the same user
    // but this if statement always returns true
    if(!empty($bookmark)) { 
        $bookmark = Bookmark::create(array(
             'user_id' => $user_id,
             'article_id' => $article_id,
         ));

        if($bookmark) {
            return View::make('article.view')
               ->with('article', $article)
               ->with('bookmarked', true);  
        }       
    } else {
        // Does not work
        $bookmark->delete();

        return View::make('article.view')
               ->with('article', $article)
               ->with('bookmarked', false);
    }

    return Redirect::route('article-all')
           ->with('global', 'We were unable to bookmark the article. Please, try again later.');
}
```

And here is part of my view:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'BookmarkController@postBookmark')) }}  
    <input 
         type="checkbox" 
         name="id" 
         onClick="this.form.submit()"
         value="{{ $article->id }}" 
         id="bookmark" 
         {{ $bookmarked ? 'checked' : '' }}
    />
    <label for="bookmark">Bookmark</label>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I do also have a route with a post method for this functionality. I would highly appreciate if anyone could give any idea of why it does not work.

Comment: Note: `Auth::user()->id` can be written as `Auth::id()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I ended up using both of your solutions.

```
    public function postBookmark() {
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $article_id = Input::get('id');
        $bookmark = User::find($user_id)->bookmarks()->where('article_id', '=', $article_id)->first();

        if(empty($bookmark)) {
             $bookmark = Bookmark::create(array(
                 'user_id' => $user_id,
                 'article_id' => $article_id,
             ));

             if($bookmark) {
                 return     Redirect::route('article-get', array('article_id' => $article_id));
             }
        } else {
             $bookmark->delete();
             return     Redirect::route('article-get', array('article_id' => $article_id));
        }   
        return  Redirect::route('article-all')
            ->with('global', 'We were unable to bookmark the article. Please, try again later.');
    }
```

Nonetheless, what I really needed to fix was my view. For some reason the id of my input was not being submitted properly, so I ended up creating a hidden field for it as well.

```
     {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'BookmarkController@postBookmark')) }}     
         <input 
             type="checkbox" 
            name="id" 
            onClick="this.form.submit()"
            value="{{ $article->id }}" 
            id="bookmark" 
            {{ $bookmarked ? 'checked' : '' }}
         />

         <input 
              type="hidden"
             name="id" 
             value="{{ $article->id }}"  
         />
        <label for="bookmark">Bookmark</label>
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not executing your bookmark query.

The `$boomark` variable in your code example is a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` object and `empty($boomark)` will return always `false` because there is a object stored.

To execute a query you can use `get()` for example. In your case you want only one result, then you use `first()` to retrieve the first found bookmark object.

Change:

```
$bookmark = Bookmark::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->where('article_id', '=', $article_id);
```

To this:

```
$bookmark = Bookmark::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->where('article_id', '=', $article_id)->first();
```

Then it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want, changing the condition `if(!empty($bookmark))` to `if ($bookmark->count()) {` might do the trick, but it will do another query with `COUNT()` to the DB and it is not really a good way of doing it.

The problem is with `if(!empty($bookmark))`, because `$bookmark` has a `QueryBuilder` instance, it will never be empty.

The preferred way would be using Eloquent model relations. With relationships you could check by `Article::has('bookmark')` for instance.